# How to get Second Most repeated Word in String using Maps

Tags: java, collections

I am trying to get the second most repeated word in the sentence.

eg:

**`String paraString = "This is a paragraph with multiple strings. Get the second most repeated word from the paragraph text and print the words with count".`**

Here 'the' is repeated for thrice and 'paragraph' & 'with' are repeated twice.

I need to print the second most repeated words 'paragraph' & 'with'.

Here is the program which I wrote to get the First Most Repeated Words.

```
public Set<String> getMostRepeatedWords(Map<String, Integer> sortedMap) {
    Set<String> mostRepeatedWords = new HashSet<String>();
    int mostrepeatedWord = Collections.max(sortedMap.values());
    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : sortedMap.entrySet()) {
        if (mostrepeatedWord == entry.getValue()) {
            mostRepeatedWords.add(entry.getKey());
        }
    }

    return mostRepeatedWords;
}
```

Please help me out.

The one option which I have is below. Let me know if there are any other ways.

```
int mostrepeatedWord = Collections.max(sortedMap.values())-1;
```

Comment: what happens when you have two words with the same mostrepeatedWord number?

Comment: Have you tried a construct with Collections.frequency()? You could then create a map where key is the result from frequency and the value is the String... If you use the proper map, you might be able to get Entrylist sorted by the key?

Comment: @Leo : I will iterate and print using the below method : 'public void printKeys(Set<String> keys) {
  for (String k : keys) {
   System.out.println(k);
  }
 }'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Following your solution***
So you have `getMostRepeatedWords` and now want the second most repeated words.
In pseudo-code this would be:

```
Map<String, Integer> sortedMap = ...;
SortedMap<String, Integer> rest = new TreeMap<>(sortedMap);
rest.removeAll(getMostRepeatedWords(sortedMap));
Set<String> secondMostRepeatedWords = getMostRepeatedWords(rest);
```

Remove the most repeated words and then on the rest get the most repeated words.

***More effort***
You could also copy the values, sort them decreasingly, and then take the second lesser value:
with index > 0, and value *lesser* than first.

Comment: I tried with above code and am getting compile time error as **The method removeAll(Set<String>) is undefined for the type SortedMap<String,Integer>** as method 'getMostRepeatedWords(sortedMap)' returns Set.

Comment: As I suspect this to be homework, I did not want to provide ready-to-use code. One has to use `remove(String)`.

Comment: Here is the code which gets the second most repeated word   'Map<String,Integer> secondMap = map;
  Set<String> mostRepeatedWords = getMostRepeatedWords(secondMap);
  secondMap.keySet().removeAll(mostRepeatedWords);
  
  Set<String> secondMostRepeatedWords = getMostRepeatedWords(secondMap);
  System.out.println(secondMostRepeatedWords);'

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of what you could do with Java 8 :

```
public List<String> getMostRepeatedWords(String s) {
    Map<String,Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    String[] words  = s.split("\\s+");
    for (String word : words) 
        map.put(word,map.containsKey(word) ? map.get(word) + 1 : 0);

    List<Entry<String,Integer>> tmp = new ArrayList<>(map.entrySet());
    Collections.sort(tmp,(e1,e2) -> Integer.compare(e2.getValue(),e1.getValue()));

    return tmp.stream().map(e -> e.getKey()).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

This method computes the complete list of the words sorted by decreasing number of occurrences. If you don't need the whole list, you should rather store the entries of the map in an array and then apply a quickselect on it, with a custom `Comparator`. Let me know if you are interested and I'll go in further details.